# R, ggplot2: creating a single legend in a bubble chart with positive and negative values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, bubble-chart

I want to create a single legend for a bubble chart with positive and negative values like in plot [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCeYR.png), generated using sp::bubble().

[image]

But, for various reasons I want to duplicate this in ggplot2. The closest I have gotten is to generate a single legend with scaled symbols, but the actual bubbles themselves are'nt scaled.

[image]

The above plot was created using the code below

```
# create data frame
x=sample(seq(1,50),50,T)
y=sample(seq(1,50),50,T)
plot_dat=data.frame(x=x,y=y,value=rnorm(50,0,25))

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=plot_dat, aes(x=x, y=y,colour=factor(sign(value)), size=value)) +
geom_point() +  
scale_size(breaks = c(-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40,50), range = c(0.5,4)) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c("orange", "blue"), guide=F) +
guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = list("orange","orange","orange","orange","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue"),size=c(3,2.5,2,1,0.5,1,2,2.5,3,4))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continue using abs(value) for size and sign(value) for color.

Provide the `breaks=` argument of `scale_size_continuous()` with duplicates of breaks required (e.g. c(10,10,20,20,...)). Next, provide `labels=` with the values you desire. Finally, use `guides()` and `override.aes` to set your own order of values and colours.

```
ggplot(data=plot_dat, aes(x=x, y=y,colour=factor(sign(value)), size=abs(value))) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("orange","blue"),guide=FALSE)+
      scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,50,50),labels=c(-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,20,30,40,50),range = c(1,5))+
      guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = list("orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue"),
                                               size=c(4.92,4.14,3.50,2.56,1.78,1.78,2.56,3.50,4.14,4.92))))
```

To assign exact values for the `size=` argument in the `guides()` function you could use function `rescale()` from the `scales` library. Rescale the entire range of values you are plotting, along with the break points provided to  `range=` argument in `scale_size_continuous()`.

```
set.seed(1234)
x=sample(seq(1,50),50,T)
y=sample(seq(1,50),50,T)
plot_dat=data.frame(x=x,y=y,value=rnorm(50,0,20))

library(scales)
rescale(c(abs(plot_dat$value),10,20,30,40,50),to=c(1,5))[51:55]
[1] 1.775906 2.562657 3.349409 4.136161 4.922912
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Didzis! The rescale function is a nice addition.