# R ggplot bubble chart legend with positive and negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a bubble chart, with size of the dots proportional to a value.
I tried with the following code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703656/r-ggplot2-creating-a-single-legend-in-a-bubble-chart-with-positive-and-negativ/50704740?noredirect=1#comment88419408_50704740)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Condition, y=variable, colour=factor(sign(as.numeric(value))), 
                size=abs(as.numeric(value)))) 
+ geom_point() 
+ scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red"), guide=FALSE) 
+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
+ scale_size_continuous(limits=c(-12, 12), 
                        breaks=c(2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12), 
                        labels=c(-12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), 
                        name="fold-change", range = c(1, 7))
+ guides(size = guide_legend(override.ae = 
                               list(size=c(6.34, 5.4, 4.44, 3.50, 2.56, 1.78, 
                                           1.78, 2.56, 3.50, 4.44, 5.4, 6.34))))
```

The problem is that the bubble in the plot are not scaled. 
Here is the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8WSo.png) I obtain.

[image]

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703656/r-ggplot2-creating-a-single-legend-in-a-bubble-chart-with-positive-and-negativ/50704740?noredirect=1#comment88419408_50704740), someone suggest to use `rescale()` function, but i didn't manage to find how ? Any suggestion ?

Here are the data I used to generate the plot :

```
Condition   variable    value
Cond1   CAMP1   NA
Cond2   CAMP1   NA
Cond3   CAMP1   -1.09680158184917
Cond4   CAMP1   NA
Cond1   CAMP3   -2.11519974938544
Cond2   CAMP3   NA
Cond3   CAMP3   -3.69892964715416
Cond4   CAMP3   NA
Cond1   CAMP23  7.06300132012619
Cond2   CAMP23  1.38072944850355
Cond3   CAMP23  5.72052199524444
Cond4   CAMP23  1.38675577543487
Cond1   CAMP25  10.6416932316709
Cond2   CAMP25  4.43600855148748
Cond3   CAMP25  10.1200460237359
Cond4   CAMP25  4.17180729151797
Cond1   CAMP26  -1.01178185945991
Cond2   CAMP26  NA
Cond3   CAMP26  NA
Cond4   CAMP26  NA
Cond1   CAMP29  NA
Cond2   CAMP29  NA
Cond3   CAMP29  -2.26897328234847
Cond4   CAMP29  -1.04075218615949
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think you have a problem with your `limits`, since the variable you give to `size` an absolute value.  Try something like `limits = c(NA, 12)`.

Comment: Remove the `limits = c(-12, 12)` bit, and see if that's closer to what you want. I think with the limits set like that, the dots *are* scaled, but you can't see it well because your actual values, at least in this sample, are more concentrated toward the middle, so the distribution becomes obscured.

Comment: I already tried, but the bubble are still not scaled.Even if I remove limits()

Comment: Only setting the upper limit works for me in version ggplot2 2.2.1.  So does removing the limits, except then the limits only go to 10 (and you want them to go to 12).

Comment: what do you mean by "upper limit" ? Could you please send me your code ? thanks

Comment: My first comment shows setting the upper limit: `limits = c(NA, 12)`.  Also, FYI, to response to someone directly you can use "@" with their username, such as @PIFASTE

Comment: @aosmith looking at value in the data.frame and bubble sizes in the graph show differences. Don't know why the bubble in the graph are not scaled with the bubble in the legend and how to modify it :(

Comment: Based on the answer you linked to it seems like you'd want to set the point size in the legend to your scale of 1-7, not to a scale of 1-5.  Like `scales::rescale(c(abs(tmp$value), 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), to = c(1,7))[25:30]`

Comment: @aosmith this is the point I don't understand, where do I have to add this information ? In the `guide()` function ? Like : `guides(size = guide_legend(override.ae = 
                               list(size=scales::rescale(c(abs(tmp$value), 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), to = c(1,7))[25:30])))`